# C++ Reusing objects to achieve Polymorphism using Abstract Base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am new to C++ and figuring out how to use polymorphism for a particular project I am working on.

I have a list of components. Each component has a score associated with it which is computed using a logic. So I have an abstract class:

```
class Component {
    public:
        int compute_score(request *r) =0;
        int get_score() { return score; }
    protected:
        int score;
};
```

Now every Component inherits from this abstract base class to implement its own logic to compute the component score. And the final algorithm is to combine all the Component scores.

```
// Compute and combine scores
for (int ndx = 0; ndx < num_components; ndx++) {
    total += components[ndx]->compute_score();
}
combined_score = total/num_components;
```

Now I am trying to fit this model in to an existing code base. There is a big struct called request to which I want to add these Component objects and compute scores.

```
struct request {
    ...
    Component *components[num_components];
    ...
};

void serve(request *r) {
    ...
    // Compute and combine scores
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < num_components; ndx++) {
        total += components->compute_score();
    }
    combined_score = total/num_components;
    ...
}

// Listener
void start(request *r) {
    // Listen for request
    // Serve the request
    serve(&r);
    // Clear the request struct for reuse
    memset(r, 0, sizeof(request)); 
} 

int main() {
    // Created only once and then reused
    request *req = (request*) calloc(1, sizeof(calloc));
    start(&req);
}
```

Possibilities for using the components array:

1. Create component sub class objects dynamically while serve() is called and free the memory that was dynamically allocated every time a request comes in. This approach ends up creating objects for each and every request and might hit performance(allocation & free) and can cause memory fragmentation.
2. Create component sub class objects statically inside the request object and point their references to the component array. I am not sure if this is a good idea, but solves the problem by reusing the same objects. And I am not sure how to go about achieving this in a simple and elegant way? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You first say "I have a list of components" and later say that in order to use it you must create sub class objects. In my understanding the pointers in the array would point to existing components (that have been created in whatever way some time before). To me it's not clear what the situation is.  That said, you probably want to index components and pass the request, right? I.e.  (`components[ndx]->compute_score(r)`).

Comment: I want to create all component objects only once and reuse the same for every request that comes in. Is there a good way to make pointers in the array to point to these objects if they are all going to be in the same struct?

Answer (score 1):

Do the simplest solution first.

Option 1 *might* hit performance. That is a big *might*. If I were you I'd use that approach because it's simpler.

*If* you encounter performance problems and *if* you can prove that it is the allocation & free that is causing it only then should you consider optimising the solution.

The last thing you want is unnecessarily complicated code.

Comment: I second that. Unless you do high speed trading or want to compute Wunderfon's 200 million invoices overnight memory management overhead is almost certainly of no concern. But I still don't quite understand the prob. If the pointers should point to members in the struct: Yes, that's possible, why not? Consider using a vector, too.

Comment: Yes my application handles around 500 million requests a day. Around 6000/sec. That is why I am concerned as to which would be a better approach. I will go with dynamic allocation and see how it affects performance to get a better understanding.